# How to merge Excel data with an Excel template to output Excel workbooks?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet workbook with data per raws:

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|   shapes  |  property 1|  property 2 |
*-----------+------------+-------------+
|   S1      +    20      |   glop      |
+-----------+------------+-------------*
|   S2      +    10      |   rrrr      |
+-----------+------------+-------------*
```

and a template workbook like this one in pseudocode:

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|   shape   |    Name    |  property 2 |
*-----------+------------+-------------+
|           +  <shapes>  | <property 2>|
+-----------+------------+-------------*
```

and I want to produce as many workbooks as data in rows like this:

**workbook 1:**

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|   shape   |    Name    |  property 2 |
*-----------+------------+-------------+
|           +    S1      |   glop      |
+-----------+------------+-------------*
```

**workbook 2:**

```
+-----------+------------+-------------+
|   shape   |    Name    |  property 2 |
*-----------+------------+-------------+
|           +    S2      |   rrrr      |
+-----------+------------+-------------*
```

How can I do it please under `Excel 2010` without `POWER QUERY` and possibly without `VBA`? Actually, my need is like a mailing from workbook contact that generates workbooks instead of sending emails.

Comment: Mailing is a special programmed function. VBA is the way to program a similar function. Here is one of many source codes for the task of [How To Create Multiple Worksheets From A List Of Cell Values](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4386-excel-create-multiple-sheets-from-list.html). You may need to google "excel 2010" or make the needed 2010 adjustments.

Comment: That helps but I am not a VBA programmer. I can do it with enough examples covering my needs thought. Do you have other links to open a template and write in a new file for each sheet, and another one to read some cells in the sheet where the VBA is and write some cells in the output sheet ?

Comment: You're using the word spreadsheet. Do you mean Worksheet within a workbook?  Ideally the code would live in its own workbook file. You can open the code workbook file and run the macro. The macro would require 3 other file names: template file, data source file and new output file name. The new output file would have a worksheet (with the format defined in the template file) for every data row in the data source file. Is this the scenario?

Comment: If there is only one template that may change over time and you never use anything other than the current template, then the code could live in the template file. The template format could be updated by modifying constants at the beginning of the macro or could exist on a sheet of the template file as you described. In the new workbook, will the worksheet names be specified by the template (shape name instead of the default "Sheet 1")? If using the shape name (or a worksheet name column described by the template) then these worksheet names need to follow the worksheet naming rules.

Comment: You are right, I have corrected : workbook  instead of speadsheet. The code will be with the data as I want to be able to change the template. There will be one file per raw data in the output.